# WPF Line breaks in string resources

Tags: c#, wpf, string

In my WPF application I'm referencing strings from a centralized dictionary resource. How can I put line breaks in these strings?

I tried `"line1\nline2", "line1\\nline2" and "line1&#x0a;line2"`, but none are working.

I should mention that I'm also including tokens in these strings ({0},...) and later using string.format(resource, args) in run-time.

Comment: If u need to put line breaksa, why don't you split the string in 2 different strings?

Comment: You should add `xml:space="preserve"` to your ResourceDictionary or in single resource.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Working solution: shift+enter in the dictionary resource window in visual studio seems to work.

Answer (score 14):

Try to add `xml:space="preserve"` to your resource and use `&#13;`

```xml
<sys:String x:Key="MyString" xml:space="preserve">line1&#13;line2</sys:String>
```

Comment: xml:space="preserve" breaks it in my test. Also note you forgot the semicolon.

Comment: Yea you forgot the semicolan. It should be &#13;

Comment: 2022 update .net4.8: adding `xml:space="preserve"` + Just copy pasting the original content makes it work.

Answer (score 5):

Try the [numeric character reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) approach:

```
<sys:String>line1&#13;line2</sys:String>
```

Note, however, that if you are actually encoding an `Inline` you can use:

```
<LineBreak />
```

E.g:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
         line1 <LineBreak /> line2
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Note `xml:space="preserve"` is required for the hex literal.

Comment: `xml:space="preserve"` broke it when I tested it.

Comment: Weird. I'm getting the string resource with `Application.Current.FindResource()` and passing it to `MessageBox.Show()`, to present a multi-line error message. Without `preserve` it just clumps into one line. ([example](https://github.com/fadden/6502bench/blob/8d78ce028a1bfcfdd6bbbf1383d647b0766c06e2/SourceGenWPF/Res/Strings.xaml#L56))

Comment: "*Try the hex literal [...] &#13;*" seems very decimal but not very literal.

Answer (score 2):

If nothing works out, assured solution would be using a converter.

```
public class NewLineConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var s = string.Empty;

        if (value.IsNotNull())
        {
            s = value.ToString();

            if (s.Contains("\\r\\n"))
                s = s.Replace("\\r\\n", Environment.NewLine);

            if (s.Contains("\\n"))
                s = s.Replace("\\n", Environment.NewLine);

            if (s.Contains("&#x0a;&#x0d;"))
                s = s.Replace("&#x0a;&#x0d;", Environment.NewLine);

            if (s.Contains("&#x0a;"))
                s = s.Replace("&#x0a;", Environment.NewLine);

            if (s.Contains("&#x0d;"))
                s = s.Replace("&#x0d;", Environment.NewLine);

            if (s.Contains("&#10;&#13;"))
                s = s.Replace("&#10;&#13;", Environment.NewLine);

            if (s.Contains("&#10;"))
                s = s.Replace("&#10;", Environment.NewLine);

            if (s.Contains("&#13;"))
                s = s.Replace("&#13;", Environment.NewLine);

            if (s.Contains("<br />"))
                s = s.Replace("<br />", Environment.NewLine);

            if (s.Contains("<LineBreak />"))
                s = s.Replace("<LineBreak />", Environment.NewLine);
        }

        return s;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The best and easy way if you are using the text editor for the resx file is by pressing

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

for every new line that you want, as noted in other answers.

If you are using text from other source and you are copying/pasting the text in the resx, then the Visual Studio will paste the text in the same format as it already is, which will include the linebreaks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the reps to comment, so I will add to IVAAAN123's answer which works fine for me (with the semi-colon), however, if you add any line-breaks in the text (to make it more readable, make sure you have no tabs in the XML so the new line starts at the edge of the page, not tabbed into the page, otherwise the 'xml:space="preserve"' will include the whitespace at the start of each line:

```
<system:String x:Key="KeyName" xml:space="preserve">
    First line of text.&#13;
    Second line of text.
</system:String>
```

...will display all spaces in front of each line.  It will also display two extra line-breaks: just before the first line and after 
 as the physical line-breaks in the text are also used. Remove the white-space and extra line-breaks and it works.